# Jackson v2.10.2 compatibility with v2.9.8?

Tags: java, jackson, dependencies, pom.xml, parent-pom

My codebase is a monolith one and a lot of different small projects are using the following mentioned jackson libraries; If I change the parent pom all of these numerous projects will be affected - hence it is important for me to know the backward compatibility of these libraries and impact of their upgrade.

Is the `v2.10.2` of the following jackson libraries :

```
jackson-core
jackson-annotations
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations
jackson-module-paranamer
jackson-module-afterburner
jackson-databind
jackson-dataformat-xml
jackson-dataformat-csv
jackson-dataformat-cbor
jackson-dataformat-smile
jackson-datatype-jdk8
jackson-dataformat-yaml
jackson-module-scala_2.11
```

backward compatible with their `v2.9.8` version ? What is the best way to find that out?
I tried to find out about this online but I could only find explanations between upgrading `v1.x` to `v2.x`. Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can always go through the release documentation to understand whether there are any breaking changes or not with the `jackson` version upgrade from `2.9` to `2.10` . The release doc for version 2.10 had the lines :

> No changes to minimum JDK baselines for use since 2.9, but 2.10
>   includes JDK 9+ compliant module-info.class which should improve
>   forward-compatibility. Older versions of tools may have issues with
>   this class.

which means that if your project is already working on java 8 you should not have any issues with the upgrade. But please go through the doc for [2.10](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.10) . Also doc for version [2.9](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.9).

Comment: There are a lot of change lists in upgrade from 2.9.8 to 2.10.2 ; Are you suggesting me to go through all the change lists and see if there are any class attributes removed or method signature/class name changes (assuming that is the definition of a breaking change)

Comment: @shireen When there are breaking changes from previous version they will explicitly call them out in the documentation and apart from the requirement that java 8 is needed to run this version I couldn't find anything else. So unless you could find something int the documentation that might be a potential issue in your specific code implementations, there is no need to worry.

Comment: There are breaking changes concerning the handling of polymorphic types.